# How to manage native looks of switch widget in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I want to create switch/toggle widget in **Flutter/Dart** with native looks of different OS.
 I mean if I run on iOS mobile it should be looks like:

[image]

If I run on Android mobile it should be looks like :

[image]

Help me to achieve this type of functionality in flutter/dart

Comment: you can watch this tutorial here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TYNbMnaEnmA

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Use [Switch.adaptive](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Switch/Switch.adaptive.html)

> Creates a CupertinoSwitch if the target platform is iOS, creates a material design switch otherwise.

```
Switch.adaptive(value: true, onChanged: (newValue) {})
```

---

**Sample code:**

```
bool _value = true;

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(),
    body: Switch.adaptive(
      value: _value,
      onChanged: (newValue) => setState(() => _value = newValue),
    ),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can check what platform the user is on and then display the appropriate platform-specific widget. `Switch` is the Android widget for toggles and `CupertinoSwitch` is the iOS equivalent. The arguments are the same for both widgets so CopsOnRoad's solution is a bit more succinct but this is another way to get platform-specific widgets.

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:io';

Platform.isAndroid ? Switch() : CupertinoSwitch()
```