# Create radio button on / off

Tags: flutter

I need to create an on / off button in the style of ios in flutter, some way or component that allows it to be done ?, I have tried in several ways but it does not work.

example
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Mh9G.png)

Comment: Try two buttons, but quit, I no longer have the code, I'm looking for some component or some way. Thanks for the help friend.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to manage native looks of switch widget in flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58319811/how-to-manage-native-looks-of-switch-widget-in-flutter)

Comment: Thanks for answering, it looks good, only yes / no text needed, I'll investigate :)

Comment: Apparently it doesn't allow to change color and label.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **custom_switch** package: https://pub.dev/packages/custom_switch

Here it's the Basic Usage:

```
class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {

  bool status = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Custom Switch Example'),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            CustomSwitch(
              activeColor: Colors.pinkAccent,
              value: status,
              onChanged: (value) {
                print("VALUE : $value");
                setState(() {
                  status = value;
                });
              },
            ),
            SizedBox(height: 12.0,),
            Text('Value : $status', style: TextStyle(
              color: Colors.black,
              fontSize: 20.0
            ),)
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

And the Example:

[image: Example]

Comment: Thanks for the help, it is very close, but I cannot change the labels, it only appears "on / off", I need "yes / no"

Comment: Dear, thank you very much for all your help, finally I stayed with CupertinoSwitch, which is the one that came closest to what I needed, the only detail that you cannot put a "yes / no" label, but it works for me anyway, thanks for all your collaboration.